# UITableView pops up no data before it has the data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, hpple

I am using hpple to get data from web page and display it in table view, but i want to cells to display " no data" if there either is no data or it can't get the data. But because of this it flases the no data on the view controller for about a second when the data is loaded here is the code i am using:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            if ((_deli.count > 0)) {
                return _deli.count;
            }
            else {
                return 1;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if ((_entrees.count > 0)) {
                return _entrees.count;
            }
            else {
                return 1;
            }
            break;
     }
     return 0
}
```

and then

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    }
    //[UIColor colorWithRed:191.0f/255.0f green:48/255.0f blue:48/255.0f alpha:1.0]
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT" size:17.0f];

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        if ([tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] == _deli.count ) {
            Items *thisDeli = [_deli objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = thisDeli.title;

        }
        else { cell.textLabel.text = @"No Data Avaiable";
        }

    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        if ([tableView numberOfRowsInSection:1] == _entrees.count) {
            Items *thisEntree = [_entrees objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = thisEntree.title;


        }
        else { cell.textLabel.text = @"No Data Avaiable";
        }

    }
}
```

Is there a way to delay the appearance of the "no data" phrase or only display it if it is blank or can't get it.

Heres my NSURLConnection

```
- (void) loadDataUsingNSURLConnection {
    NSString *url = @"http://ueat.site88.net/westTest.xml";
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        NSLog(@"response == %@", response);
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Cheers

Comment: Based on your question, it sounds like it is doing exactly what you want it to. When there is no data, it shows no data. When it gets data, it no longer shows no data. Can you elaborate and describe your desired outcome?

Comment: @quellish sure. So basically before the data has loaded the "No data available" flashes on the screen for a second or two and then once the data has loaded it displays that, but I only want the "No data available" to display if there was like a connection error or something. does that clarify things?

Comment: Err OK, what do you want it to do when there is no data, but there was not a connection error or something? Again, not real clear on your intent. The recommended thing to do would be to show an empty state, and while it's attempting to get data show progress of some kind. If there is a connection error, present the error to the user. In your case using sendAsynchronousRequest a lot of the work is done for you. Show progress before that method, end progress within the completion block. If there is no data, present the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider making the "No Data Available" string dynamic based on whether your call has completed to load the data or not. If the call has not completed have it use "Loading" or something like that. If the call has completed have it show the existing "No Data Available" string.

EDIT WITH EXAMPLE:

The easiest thing to do, with the code you have, is to set your `_deli` and `_entrees` variables to `nil` until you've loaded them, and check for that condition when displaying your message:

```
@interface YourViewController ()
{
    NSArray *_deli;
    NSArray *_entrees;
}
@end
```

Set the arrays to nil in your `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _deli = nil;
    _entrees = nil;
}
```

Change the logic in your previous code to this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            if (_deli == nil || _deli.count == 0) {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return _deli.count;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if (_entrees == nil || _entrees.count == 0) {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return _entrees.count;
            }
            break;
     }

     return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    }
    //[UIColor colorWithRed:191.0f/255.0f green:48/255.0f blue:48/255.0f alpha:1.0]
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT" size:17.0f];

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        if (_deli == nil)
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Loading";
        else if (_deli.count > 0) {
            Items *thisDeli = [_deli objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = thisDeli.title;
        }
        else 
            cell.textLabel.text = @"No Data Avaiable";
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        if (_entrees == nil)
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Loading";
        else if (_entrees.count > 0) {
            Items *thisEntree = [_entrees objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = thisEntree.title;
        }
        else
            cell.textLabel.text = @"No Data Avaiable";
    }
}
```

Since your `loadDataUsingNSURLConnection` just writes out the response I'm not sure how you're loading the array, but you should get the idea at this point. All you need to do is just load the response into the array and call the `reloadData` method on your table to get the new data to appear.

Comment: okay I'm using NSURULConnection i have added the code i use above, could you post the if statement of how to check if it is either loading, failed, or finished loading.